How to calculate FPS (frame rate) in Qt app using QtWebEngineView
I created a simple project, it displays the location of the vehicle (read from a csv file) on a google map using QtWebEngineView. The way it works is that every 16ms (I expected that it will display with 60 FPS) it will read 1 location data (lat, lon) from the csv file and display the corresponding maker on the map. But I don't know whether the actual FPS is as expected or not, how to display the actual FPS on the screen?
MyMap.qml
Window {
    id: myMap
    title: "Google Map"
    width: 1600
    height: 900

    QtObject{
        id: backendId
        WebChannel.id: "backend"
    }

    WebChannel {
        id: myWebChannel
        registeredObjects: backendId
    }

    WebEngineView {
        id: webview
        anchors.fill: parent
        webChannel: myWebChannel
        settings.javascriptEnabled: true
        url: "html/index.html"

        settings {
            autoLoadImages: true
            dnsPrefetchEnabled: false
            accelerated2dCanvasEnabled: true
            javascriptEnabled: true
            webGLEnabled:true
            pdfViewerEnabled: false
        }
    }
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Google Maps Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="qwebchannel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-container">
        <div id="map"></div>
            <div class="velocity">
                    <p id="Fps">0 </p>
            </div>
    </div>

    <br>
        <script async
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.54&key=apiKey&language=ja&callback=initMap">
        </script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    <br>
</body>
</html>


index.js
// Define
let TILT = 55;
let HEADING = 0;
let ZOOM = 18;

// Variable
let map;
let directionsRenderer;
let directionsService;

let backend;
let rawMarker;
let icon;

//calculate fps
let m_fps;
let prevTime;
let curTime;
let isFirstCount;

// Function
function initMap() {
    var webChannel = new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel){
        backend = channel.objects.backend;
    });

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    rawMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: { lat: 21.007571859312662, lng: 105.79382411840304 },
       map: map,
       draggable: false,
       title: "Raw Marker",
       icon: {
           url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
           scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 40) 
       }
   });

    fps_disp = document.getElementById("Fps");

    //fps
    m_fps = 0;
    prevTime = 0;
    curTime = 0;
    isFirstCount = true;
}

function getLocation(lat0, lon0) {
    var rawLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat0, lon0);

    myMarker.setPosition(rawLocation);
    map.setCenter(rawLocation);
    calFps();
}


function calFps() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        curTime = performance.now();
        if(isFirstCount) {
            isFirstCount = false;
            prevTime = curTime;
        }

        if(curTime-prevTime>= 1000) {
            dispFps(m_fps)
            m_fps = 0;
            prevTime = curTime;
        } else {
            m_fps++;
        }
      });
}

function dispFps(m_fps){
    fps_disp.innerHTML = "<b>FPS:</b> " + m_fps;
}


The function  getLocation() is called every 16ms and it will update marker of vehicle on the map. I tried calculating FPS by calculating the number of calls to the getLocation() function in 1 second, however I understood this incorrectly. FPS depends on rendering the map every time I drag and drop the QML window or zoom in/zoom out the map. Please help me with this problem

What does it have to do with C++?

Sorry my bad, my project have something processed by C++ but this section is not related to C++
